# Image won't send to my backend in my Alamofire .post request - Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, alamofire

I'm creating a login process and everything works fine, but now I'm trying to implement a client profile photo feature and send the photo to the backend (my backend developer has AWS to handle images). I keep getting an error, I'll attach photos.

**First photo:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAAQh.jpg

**Second photo:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVuFG.jpg

The **first photo** is my Postman response, note how it is using form-data for the body. I think this is where my error lies because in my code I just create a body property that is a simple dictionary, but I'm not sure if Alamofire has requests for form-data, and if so, how to implement them here? In the form-data I submit "file": My image, and "clientID": id, the response is an object. I'm trying to get the **"_id"** from the **"profilePictures"** array of objects. My logic for parsing the JSON might be off, the code for that will be in the second photo.

In the **second photo** I screen shotted the function responsible for the error, in the Xcode debugger you'll notice the error **'Invalid type in JSON write (UIImage)'** which further leads me to believe that sending an image through an Alamofire post request is a bad idea. So now that you've seen my code and the Postman response, what do you guys think is going wrong? Does the form-data body matter and if so how do I correct this? Any help is appreciated, let me know if there is more details you need about my situation.

HERE IS SOME CODE FOR REFERENCE IF NECESSARY:

```
func sendClientProfileToAWS(profileImage: UIImage, id: String, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

// First grab the image and then the id of the client (NOTE: Client must already be created to use this)
    let body: [String: Any] = [
        "file": profileImage,
        "clientID": id
    ]

    Alamofire.request(CLIENT_UPLOAD_PROFILE_PHOTO, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: HEADER).responseJSON { (response) in
        print(response)
        print("Uploading image file to db")
        if response.result.error == nil {
            print(response.result)

            if let jsonDict = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                let profile = jsonDict["profilePictures"] as? [[String: Any]]
                for id in profile! {
                    if let clientProfile = id["_id"] as? String {
                        self.clientPhotoId = clientProfile
                        print("Photo ID - \(clientProfile)")
                    }
                }
            }
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
            debugPrint(response.result.error as Any)
        }
    }
}
```

**New Updated code:**

```
func sendClientProfileToAWS(profileImage: UIImage, id: String, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 1.0)

    let url = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string:CLIENT_UPLOAD_PROFILE_PHOTO)!, method: .post, headers: HEADER)

    Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "file", fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
    },
        with: url,
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                    print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })

                **// Upload progress completes but the responses below never run?**

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                        print(response.request!)  // original URL request
                        print(response.response!) // URL response
                        print(response.data!)     // server data
                        print(response.result)
                        if let jsonDict = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                            print("In JSON")
                            let profile = jsonDict["profilePictures"] as? [[String: Any]]
                            for id in profile! {
                                if let clientProfile = id["id"] as? String {
                                    self.clientPhotoId = clientProfile
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        self.setClientProfilePhoto(photoId: self.clientPhotoId!) // Taks photo id
                        self.getClientProfilePhoto(id: id) // Takes clientID
                        completion(true)
                    } else {
                        completion(false)
                        print("There is an error")
                    }
                }
            case .failure( _):
                break
            }
    }
    )
```

Comment: Try using multi part form data upload?

Comment: Ok, so I implemented multi part form data, but I still can't seem to get it to work. I've edited my post if you want to take a look. After the upload progress the other code isn't run as far as I can tell, but it doesn't throw an error either.

Comment: Try the answer by @Meonardo.

Answer (score 0):

1, Upload file you should use the `Alamofire.upload()` method.

2, `multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "file", fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")`
 You should ask your backend what the "name" he provides(You were writing a "file").

3, Did you forget pass the "id" to your backend? I can not see it in the second method.